# Carousel isn't taking up entire page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Here is my [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/WJdjc1mJ1C).

The problem is that on my bootply, it displays correctly, with the carousel taking up the entire width of the page.

But on my page it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how it doesn't take up the entire width of the page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was using my `_layout` view.. so at the top I needed to add

```
@{
    Layout = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Height and width of the image matters. Please use image that have more width than height like a banner.
along with that please show code how you initialize carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.carousel {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;  
}
```

Comment: sorry but still same issue.